# php multiple word search algorithm/script doesn't work with single quotes around search array variable. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, search

i've got a basic search code to search through database when people search for more than 1 word. i've done loads of research and all the algortihms seem to be prety much the same. trim the search words. `explode` them into an `array`. then use either `foreach` or `while` to add each word of array onto the `msql_query`.

but there is a problem. here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$words = $_POST['searchfield']; 
$arraySearch = explode(" ", trim($words));       
$countSearch = count($arraySearch);
$a = 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE ";

while ($a < $countSearch)
{
  $query = $query."description RLIKE '$arraySearch[$a]'";
  $a++;
  if ($a < $countSearch)
  {
    $query = $query." AND ";
    }

  }

$results=mysql_query($query) or die($query);
 if(!$results){
    $msg = "No results, please try another search";}


}
```

ok so look at the second `$query` variable where it says `"decription RLIKE '$arraySearch'"`

For the search to work whatever word is in `$arraySearch` HAS to be in single quotes. BUT when i try it the script will just not run. 
BUT if i take away the single quotes the script runs. but it doesn't perform the search. it `die`s and comes up with error. in this case i've made the error message the actual query to try and find out what's going wrong.

so if i take away the single quotes and search for "car tyre". the query will be `SELECT * FROM parts WHERE description RLIKE car AND description RLIKE tyre` but it won't work unless its like this: `SELECT * FROM parts WHERE description RLIKE 'car' AND description RLIKE 'tyre'`.

i know this because i have tested the earch by just typing it into another query to test it.

i've spent hours and hours trying to figure a way round this but i can't figure it out. why is it doing this to me? how do i get round it? and why doesn't anyone else seem to be having the same problem?????

thanx for help :)

.... added as afterthough:
 i'm thinking that the only possible way of doing this is to have the single quotes already inside the variable. but i don't know how to do that. as in: 
`$arraySearch = ("'car'", "'tyre'");` any ideas?

Comment: Why use regular expression match here?  Why not just `LIKE '%value%'`? Is your intent that someone could pass `.*` and match every record? Also you are not doing anything to escape your input, so you are very open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: i dont know why i'm using regular expression. some1 once said it was better and i believed them. it's irrelevant really though. once it works i can decide on LIKE or RLIKE later on. and yes i'll escape the input aswell, all on my to do list.....once i can get it to work.

Comment: You need use escape quote . Probably addslaches function will work or try sql equivalent

Comment: ok sorry. it turns out i've wasted hours and hours and hours of my life.....
if your interested i have finally figured it out.

to add the quotes i simple made a varibale called `$quote` and put it before and afrer `$arraySearch`

still wasnt working, and the reason was that my script was displaying the variable `$result` not `$results`....
damn that `s`. cant belive i didnt see it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the quotes to work correctly, try to write it like this:

```
$query = $query."description RLIKE '".$arraySearch[$a]."'";
```

Adding the `".` and `."` inside of the single quotes may solve your problem.

Comment: umm nope sorry that didn't work. thanx tho. i'm thinking that the only possible way of doing this is to have the single quotes already inside the variable. but i don't know how to do that. as in the `$arraySearch = ("'car'", "'tyre'");`     any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
$quote = "'";

$query = $query."description RLIKE $quote$arraySearch[$a]$quote";
```

Comment: Read the comments. The problem was not the quotes.